# How to make a request to a specific URL in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to get access to the following URL's data in Julia. I can see what appears to be a JSON object when I go to "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=Julia&site=stackoverflow". However, when I try printing the resulting `r` below, it gives me an either text that doesn't render properly, or if I do `JSON.print`, it shows me a bunch of random numbers.

How can I use Julia to get the same things I see in the browser (preferably in text form).

```
r = HTTP.request("GET", "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=Julia&site=stackoverflow"; verbose=3)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The response body is compressed with `gzip`, as you can see from the `Content-Encoding` header:

```
julia> using HTTP

julia> r = HTTP.request("GET", "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=Julia&site=stackoverflow")
HTTP.Messages.Response:
"""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip                          <----
[...]
```

so you have to decompress it with e.g. `CodecZlib`:

```
julia> using CodecZlib

julia> compressed = HTTP.payload(r);

julia> decompressed = transcode(GzipDecompressor, compressed);
```

From here you can either create a `String` (e.g. `String(decompressed)`) or parse it with e.g. the `JSON` package:

```
julia> using JSON

julia> json = JSON.parse(IOBuffer(decompressed))
Dict{String,Any} with 4 entries:
  "items"           => Any[Dict{String,Any}("link"=>"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010720/how-to-make-a-request-to-a-specific-url-in-julia","view_count"=>5,"creation_date"=…
  "quota_max"       => 300
  "quota_remaining" => 297
  "has_more"        => true
```

(See also https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/issues/256)

Comment: This is such an awesome answer that has helped me a ton. I have a followup, when I do this, there's a ton of DEBUG prints. How can I make them go away?

Comment: Don't use verbose if you dont want verbose output.